# I have a cookie that comes back as json but can't get the value?

Tags: json, angularjs, cookies

I have this cookie

```
 {"__ngDebug":"true","userdata":"j:{\"id\":10099,\"username\":\"somename@gmail.com\",\"email\":\"somename@gmail.com\",\"role\":\"candidate\"}"}
```

If I do cookie.userdata I get

```
"j:{\"id\":10099,\"username\":\"somename@gmail.com\",\"email\":\"somename@gmail.com\",\"role\":\"candidate\"}"
```

If I do `cookie.userdata.j` I get nothing.   What do I have to do to get email, username, and role?

Answer (score 3):

## The Problem

This is because the result of `cookie.userdata` is a `string` not an `object`.

Unfortunately you can not directly parse the result as JSON with `JSON.parse`, because the value of `userdata` is not valid JSON (It is object syntax without being wrapped in `{` and `}`, and `j` needs to be wrapped in `"`)

## Best Method: Fix Input At Source

To solve this issue you need to reformat you input string if possible like so,

```
{"__ngDebug":"true","userdata":{"j":{"id":10099,"username":"somename@gmail.com","email":"somename@gmail.com","role":"candidate"}}}
```

Note I added `{` and `}` to the beginning and end of `userdata` and I wrapped `j` in `"`. Also I made removed the `\` and the `"` around the value of `userdata` since we want it to be an `object` not a `string`.

Doing this, you should be able to get the value of `j` like so `cookie.userdata.j`.

If you for some reason *must* have `j` as a `string`, this will also work,

```
{"__ngDebug":"true","userdata":"{\"j\":{\"id\":10099,\"username\":\"somename@gmail.com\",\"email\":\"somename@gmail.com\",\"role\":\"candidate\"}}"}
```

Note I added `{` and `}` to the beginning and end of `userdata` and I wrapped `j` in `"`

Then you should be able to get it with `JSON.parse(cookie.userdata).j`

## Not As Good Method: But it works

If you can't fix the input at the source for some reason, you can do some fiddling with the `cookie.userdata` `string` to make it valid JSON, then use `JSON.parse` on it.

Assuming `cookie.userdata` yields the following,

```
"j:{\"id\":10099,\"username\":\"somename@gmail.com\",\"email\":\"somename@gmail.com\",\"role\":\"candidate\"}"
```

Then you can do the following to coerce it into a valid object.

```
val = cookie.userdata
objVal = JSON.parse('{' + val.replace('j:', '"j":') + '}')
j = objVal.j
```

What I am doing here is adding the JSON object delimiters `{` and `}` and wrapping `j` in `"`, which is required by the JSON standard.

## Conclusion

Using any of the above methods, once you have `j` as in object, it is a simple matter to get the `username`, `email`, and `role`.

```
j.username => "somename@gmail.com"
j.email => "somename@gmail.com"
j.role => "candidate"
```